# Ethereum/blockchain application for historic building preservation

Tags: blockchain, tokens, nft

Could I run a potential application of Ethereum past y'all and get your thoughts?  I live in a town with a strong sense of community and identity due in part to a number of distinctive historic buildings.  Many people want to preserve these buildings to maintain the town's character, but this preservation is often in conflict with the private interests that own said buildings.  My associates and I are trying to establish whether Ethereum, or similar blockchain tech, could be used to incentivise owners to preserve and maintain their buildings, and thereby to move beyond the traditional paradigm of conflict between private interest and public good.  Perhaps creating a community-owned and maintained directory of buildings, a 'digital museum' of sorts, storing information on their history and heritage and somehow rewarding owners for actions that promote them for the good of the community.

I have a basic lay understanding of blockchain tech, but I feel the devil is in the detail, and really understanding its potential needs a more technical grasp.

I guess a few basic questions:

1. If the blockchain was to be public/community property, how would lay members of the public interact with it?  Is it necessary to have a stake in the chain in order to interact with it?
2. Would mining and proof of work be required?  Would community members need to engage in this?  It's difficult to see that people in this town would be into that.
3. I think we'd want it to be public, but limited to the local area.  Does that sound possible?  I understand about private blockchains but public ownership seems to fit our premise better.
4. Is there any mileage in creating digital identities for buildings as NFTs, almost like tradeable cards? (But not actually tradeable, this isn't designed to be a marketplace for real estate!)

I would be absolutely brimming with gratitude for any thoughts on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very loaded question, but a good one as well. Blockchain technology would definitely be a good way to keep the buildings up and preserved.

I urge you to look into what Helium is doing (HNT), basically Long-Fi technology that mines on a proof of challenge when one hotspot can see another one and answer challenges. This may be a good short term entry point for your town, while you think of your own ways to maximize and maybe even develop your own chain on the Ethereum Mainnet <3

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful, I'll start with Helium.